# Question on contour integrals. $\int_C \frac{1}{1+z^2} dz$ without using ML estimation!

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

NOTE: I went though every every previous post on contour integration (here and on youtube) looking for a resolution to this question, so please do NOT mark this question as already answered.

Let $C$ be the contour $z=|r|>1$ be the upper half of a circle or radius r centered at the origin, $(Im(z)\geq 0)$, so not closed), oriented counterclockwise and suppose you want to integrate $$\int_C \frac{1}{1+z^2} dz = \int_0^\pi \frac{i r e^{ i \theta}}{1+ r^2 e^{2 i \theta}}d\theta.$$
where the integral on the righthand side of the equality has the parametrization $z=r e^{ i \theta}, dz =i r e^{ i \theta}d\theta$.

To be clear, I want show this contour integral goes to zero **directly** as r goes to infinity without using ML estimation or any estimation theorem. Now according to ML, $|\int_C \frac{1}{1+z^2} dz|\leq  \pi r/(r^2-1)$ (more details someone else wrote below) which goes to $0$ as $r\rightarrow \infty$, which you will find in the solution of every other related problem.  In summary, using ML, $\int_C \frac{1}{1+z^2} dz \rightarrow 0$ as $r\rightarrow \infty$.

But according to Mathematica:

Integrate[ r I Exp[I x]/(1 + (r Exp[I x])^2), {x, 0, Pi}] = $ \int_0^\pi \frac{i r e^{ i \theta}}{1+ r^2 e^{2 i \theta}}d\theta= -2 \arctan(r)$.
This does **not** go to zero as $r\rightarrow \infty$, but instead $-2 \arctan(r)\rightarrow -\pi$.

I also calculated it to be $-\pi$  below in a way that avoids expressions using the complex version of $Arctan(\cdot)$ by doing partial fraction decomposition.

$$\int_C \frac{1}{1+z^2}dz = \frac{i}{2}\int_C \frac{dz}{z+i}-\frac{i}{2}\int_C \frac{dz}{z-i}=\frac{i}{2} \int_0^\pi \frac{r i e^{i\theta}}{r e^{i\theta}+i}d\theta -\frac{i}{2} \int_0^\pi \frac{r i e^{i\theta}}{r e^{i\theta}-i}d\theta $$
$$= \frac{i}{2} \int_{r+i}^{-r+i} \frac{du}{u} -\frac{i}{2} \int_{r-i}^{-r-i} \frac{du}{u}.$$

From here, we can see that we can use the principal branch $\log(z)$ for each individual integral where $-\pi<Arg(z)<\pi$.

So write $r+i = R e^{i \eta}$ where  $0<\eta < \pi/2$.  Then $r-i = R e^{- i \eta}, -r-i = R e^{i (-\pi+\eta)},  -r+i = R e^{i (\pi-\eta)}$ give the angles corresponding to the principal branch

This gives $$\int_C \frac{1}{1+z^2}dz=\frac{i}{2} (\log(-r+i)-\log(r+i) - (\log(-r-i)-\log(r-i))) \\= \frac{i}{2}(i(  (\pi-\eta -\eta)- (-\pi+\eta-(-\eta) ))) =  2\eta - \pi.$$

Then as $r\rightarrow \infty$,  $\eta\rightarrow 0$, giving the answer $-\pi$, which agrees with -2 arctan(r) that wolfram gives which also goes to $-\pi$ as $r\rightarrow \infty$.

Can anyone spot where I am going wrong?

Comment: Looking at Wolfram Alpha I see $\int_0^π \frac{r i \exp(i x)}{1 + (r \exp(i x))^2} dx = -2 \tan^{-1}(r) \text{ for }-1\le r \le1$ so not valid for $|r|>1$

Comment: That is not correct.  You get back the statement

 ConditionalExpression[-2 ArcTan[r], -1 <= Im[r] <= 1.  This states that the IMAGINARY part of r must be between i and -i, since there are isolated singularities there!  You can easily get rid of the conditional statement by adding a Assuming[r in Reals.

Comment: Actually I am absolutely correct about what I see.  It may not be what you see, and it may be incorrect, but that's not what I'm claiming
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ElSV.png

Comment: What version of mathematica are you using? Mine looks identical but with Im(r) replaced with r.

If you are using Wolfram Alpha, I am going to have to assume it is a typo, but that just makes things more confusing.

Comment: Not Mathematica.  Wolfram Alpha.  Also note that the integral has to be zero by the Residue Theorem taken with the well known value for the integral over the real line.  There has to be a flaw in your reasoning somewhere.

Comment: I agree there is a flaw.  However, Wolfram Alpha is built off of Wolfram Mathematica, so it seems more likely Wolfram Alpha has a typo over Mathematica.  My guess is Wolfram Alpha isn't using the principal branch of Log(z) which forces different constraints on r.  For example in mathematica, even computing the limit Limit[Integrate[ r I Exp[I x]/(1 + (r Exp[I x])^2), {x, 0, Pi}], 
 r -> Infinity] gives -pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was here.

*From here, we can see that we can use the principal branch $\log(z)$ for each individual integral where $-\pi<Arg(z)<\pi$.*

**Explanation of what went wrong**

$\int_C \frac{1}{1+z^2}dz = \frac{i}{2}\int_C \frac{dz}{z+i}-\frac{i}{2}\int_C \frac{dz}{z-i}=\frac{i}{2} \int_0^\pi \frac{r i e^{i\theta}}{r e^{i\theta}+i}d\theta -\frac{i}{2} \int_0^\pi \frac{r i e^{i\theta}}{r e^{i\theta}-i}d\theta$

$= \frac{i}{2} \int_{r+i}^{-r+i} \frac{du}{u} -\frac{i}{2} \int_{r-i}^{-r-i} \frac{du}{u}.$

For the first integral $\frac{i}{2} \int_0^\pi \frac{r i e^{i\theta}}{r e^{i\theta}+i}d\theta = \frac{i}{2} \int_{r+i}^{-r+i} \frac{du}{u}$

Note that with $u= r e^{i\theta}+i$ gives $u$ range of values along the circle $|u|= \sqrt{r^2+1}$ from $\theta=0, u= r+i$ to $\theta=\pi, u= -r+i$  We still need to figure out if we are traversing counterclockwise (contour stays above the real axis) or clockwise. We can determine this by checking a value of $\theta$ between 0 and $\pi$, and $\pi/2$ is the obvious choice. Notice that when $\theta=\pi/2, u= 2i$, so we can see we are taking the counterclockwise contour, which doesn't go through the principal branch of log(u) since it entirely above the real axis. So using the principal branch Log() is fine here!

**Now, let's now look at the other integral, where the mistake was made**

$\frac{i}{2} \int_0^\pi \frac{r i e^{i\theta}}{r e^{i\theta}-i}d\theta=\frac{i}{2} \int_{r-i}^{-r-i} \frac{du}{u}$.

This time the starting point and ending point are slightly below the real axis. Using the logic in the previous paragraph, when $\theta=\pi/2, u= r e^{i \theta/2}-i= ri-i = (r-1)i$.  From here we see that for $r>1$, we are STILL taking the counter clockwise contour, meaning we have to cross the negative real axis, which means taking the principal branch Log(u) won't work!

However, if r<1, then taking the Principal branch is just fine as the contour is then the clockwise one that doesn't cross the negative real axis!  In other words, the wrong computation I originally had above would holds for r<1, as wolfram alpha predicted, but wolfram mathematica did not!  What we can see here choosing the principal branch in both situation gives a contour (with $r<1$) that can be deformed to  $\int_{\infty}^{-\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = -\pi$ by essentially flattening out this small circle to the real line while simultaneously stretching it out along the real axis.

**Corrected Solution**

*In both contour integrals above, we can take the antiderivative to be $log(u)$ with the branch cut $-\pi/2 \leq Arg(u)\leq 3\pi/2$ along the neative imaginary axis. Note: we don't have to use the same branch cut for both contour integrals, it is merely more convenient to do so.

So with $R=\sqrt{r^2+1}$, write $r+i = R e^{i \eta}$ where  $0<\eta < \pi/2$.  Then $r-i = R e^{- i \eta}, -r-i = R e^{i (\pi+\eta)},  -r+i = R e^{i (\pi-\eta)}$ give the angles corresponding to the principal branch

This gives $$\int_C \frac{1}{1+z^2}dz=\frac{i}{2} (\log(-r+i)-\log(r+i) - (\log(-r-i)-\log(r-i))) \\= \frac{i}{2}(i(  (\pi-\eta -\eta)- (\pi+\eta-(-\eta) ))) =  2\eta $$

Then as $r\rightarrow \infty$,  $\eta\rightarrow 0$, giving the answer $0$

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is hidden in parametrizing the integrals and then coming back and doing complex variable substitutions to go back to contour integrals.  That seems kind of dodgy ($\theta$ is a real variable, but $u$ is complex).  Instead I'd suggest thinking about the branch points of the original integrand and integrals obtained from the partial fraction decomposition and the contour deformations involved to get from your starting point to end point.  For the branch points of $\int_C \frac{1}{1+z^2}dz$,  we have $i$ and $-i$.  If we make the line segment between them a branch cut we should avoid problems down the road.  For $\frac{i}{2}\int_C \frac{dz}{z+i}$ we should think about deforming the upper half circle to the line segment from $r$ to $-r$.  Immediately we have a problem with the branch cut stopping us.  Even if we say what the hey $i$ isn't a branch point of $\frac{i}{2}\int_C \frac{dz}{z+i}$ and go ahead, we cannot shift the contour on $\frac{i}{2}\int_C \frac{dz}{z-i}$ to $r$ to $-r$ without passing through the branch point of the integrand at $i$.  If you think about it, that's what your substitutions have done.  You need a more careful analysis of the behavior of the integrals involving the branch points which is why you have an answer off by something like $\frac{i}{2}\cdot 2\pi i$

Comment: This is the closest answer yet to what I might be doing wrong.  I am going to mull over it for a bit.  It is not clear what you mean by making a branch cut from -i to i.  In general, branch cuts are rays for Log(.), not line segments. Can you elaborate a bit more on this?

In general, when parametrizing, you go from complex z, to real, $\theta$, so I am also not sure why it would be dodgy going the opposite direction.

Thanks for the post.  I will this about this some more.

Comment: The key thing to focus on is that you are effectively deforming the semi-circular contour into the line segment from $r$ to $-r$  That works for your first integral, but not for the second.  It isn't possible to continuously deform the the semi-circular contour into the line segment and avoid the singularity of the second integrand at $i$.  Any workaround will introduce extra terms that cancel the $-\pi$ you came up with for the value of your original integral.

Comment: I think I found the problem!  The issue was that I couldn't use the principal branch on the denominator $z-i$ contour integral. Last time I did this, I incorrectly sketched the z values.  It now looks like both integral will work with the log associated to the branch cut  $Im(z)\leq 0$ for the u-logarithms

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you treat $i$ as a real number in your calculation for the integral. What you should do is write the real and imaginary parts of your integrands:

$$\int_0^\pi\frac{ire^{i\theta}}{1+r^2e^{i2\theta}}d\theta=\int_0^\pi\frac{ire^{i\theta}}{1+r^2e^{i2\theta}}\frac{1+r^2e^{-i2\theta}}{1+r^2e^{-i2\theta}}d\theta=\int_0^\pi\frac{ire^{i\theta}+ir^3e^{-i\theta}}{1+2r^2\cos(2\theta)+r^4}d\theta$$

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I am not sure how this is an issue, as arctan(z)= i/2  Log((i+z)/(i-z)) where a suitable branch is chosen.

I tried the computation both by hand and via mathematica, they both don't give me what I would expect from ML estimation.

Could you explain further?

Comment: I added some more details to my computation. If you could find where I am wrong, I will very much appreciate it.

Comment: Just notice that your integral fails for $r=1$ because you have a pole at $z=\pm i$

Comment: r>1 here, and more generally interested in the behavior $r->infty$, where ML estimation theorem says that the integral should tend to zero. But I am not getting that.

Comment: Note that $\int\frac1x dx=\ln|x|$, so watch out for the absolute value.

Comment: This is complex integration. so that formula doesn't really hold, in fact the antiderivative you are looking for is $\int \frac{1}{z} dz$ = log(z), where for this log(z)=  ln r + i arg(z),   and you have to take a branch cut to find a suitable antiderivative.

Answer (score -2):

\begin{alignat*}{1}
\left|\int_C \frac{1}{1+z^2} dz \right| & = \left| \int_0^\pi \frac{i r e^{ i \theta}}{1+ r^2 e^{2 i \theta}}d\theta \right| \\
  & \le \int_0^\pi \left| \frac{ire^{ i \theta}}{1 + r^2 e^{2 i \theta}} \right| d\theta \\
  & = \int_0^\pi  \frac{\left| ire^{ i \theta} \right|}{\left| 1 + r^2 e^{2 i \theta}\right|}  d\theta \\
  & \le \int_0^\pi  \frac r{r^2 - 1}  d\theta  \quad \textrm{ since } \ \left| 1 + r^2 e^{2 i \theta}\right| \ge \left|r^2 e^{2 i \theta}\right|-1 = r^2 - 1 \\
  & = \frac{\pi r}{r^2 - 1} \to 0 \ \textrm{ as } \ r\to\infty. 
\end{alignat*}
We assumed that $r>1$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I noted in my question that I am aware of ML estimation and am trying to understand why my direct computation is not working.